# javascript hasOwnProperty() not finding property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Working with angularjs and firebase writing a function that's supposed to check whether the currentUser can be found in the database. Right now the property "attendings" only contains one user and that is "Peter Pan"

services/party.js

```
isAttending: function (party) {
      if (User.signedIn() && party.attendings) {
          console.log(User.getCurrent().username);   //Writes out: Peter Pan
          console.log(eve.attendings);               //Writes out: Peter Pan
          console.log(party.attendings.hasOwnProperty(
                 User.getCurrent().username);        //Writes out: false
      return party.attendings.hasOwnProperty(User.getCurrent().username);
    }
}
```

Peter Pan was stored when the party object was created:

```
var Party = {
  ..
  create: function (p) {
      ...
      party.attendings = user.username;
      ...
    }
}
```

The user is apperantly stored in 'attendings' but why won't hasOwnProperty() find it?

Comment: if username property is a direct property of attendings object then only hasOwnProperty will work.

Comment: Can't you simply check if the object has a `username` property like this `if (User.getCurrent().username) console.log('username = '+User.getCurrent().username)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken about how hasOwnProperty works.

hasOwnProperty will return if the object has a property, in your case, party has a property attendings for instance, but that is all it will check, it won't check what the value of this property is (in this case Peter Pan).

Now, I assume you'd like attendings to be a list, in that case you need to find a value in a list, there are several ways, if you can use jQuery you could do something like:

```
$.inArray( User.getCurrent().username, [ party.attendings ] );
```

If you don't then take a look at different alternatives just googling to find a value in an array in javascript.

Comment: thanks. Do you have any idea how to check if data exists with firebase/angularfire?

Comment: I don't know firebase/angularfire but looking at their website, and assuming that you are working with it, seems to be explained in https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: Thanks! I had an error in declaring the property:

ref.$child(partyId).$child('attendings').$child(user.username).$set(user.username)


where ref is my path to the database.